# mounting command for sdcard never exit

Tags: linux, boot, mount

My system is an embedded linux system buided with yocto kroghoth on an IMX6 based board (`$uname -a : Linux tx6s-8035 4.13.0-karo-tx6+ #2 SMP Fri Apr 26 14:05:31 CEST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux`). I have an **SDCARD** which is automatically mounted at the system boot. My problem is when the **SDCARD is corrupted, the mount command enter in infinite loop and never exit** and the system never boot. Is there a way to prevent the mount from**strong text** entering in infinite loop or just a way to know if the sdcard file-system is corrupted to avoid the mount.

Comment: Have you checked the `nofail` option in `/etc/fstab` ?

Comment: I did not use fstab for auto mounting. I make a udev rules and call a script which run the mounting command. Is mount command has nofail as default?

Answer (score 0):

I developed an embedded project many years ago using Linux on an SD cards. What it worked for me, is mounting the SD card as read-only.

For any partition that should have writteable access (/var, p.e.), I created a tmpfs file and mounted on memory. Of course, any data written in here will be lost after reboot. You can remotely syslog info if you need it.

If you still need access to a read-write partition in a non-volatile way (like a data logger, p.e.), create a separated partition for this, and be carefull with the amount of data being writted.

Comment: The SD card memory is for me a data logger. The problem is that the system is not permanently conneted to network to remotely get data by network. That 's why the SD card is here. My issue is that during the mount of the SD card. If the filesystem of SD card is not corrupted, every thing work well but when the filesystem is corrupted the mount process is in D state (uninterruptible sleep) and for me there no way to kill the process. Moreover, this process occupies all the cpu resources making the reboot impossible.

Comment: For data loggers, you should not use any filesystem type that uses journaling (like ext3/4). Vfat suit better for this. Try to format the partition that will store the data logger info as vFat (fat 32). Force a sanity filesystem check on every boot for this specific partition.